# ModelBuilder layer name output is not unique

Tags: modelbuilder, layers, arcgis-pro, file-path

After using inline variable substitution in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder it generated the outputs that I wanted, but their layer names in the output were not unique. In the metadata tab, I can see that the feature class is named as I wanted it, but it's not displayed as the layer name. Is it possible to make corrections to the model so it would rename them correctly or create a script that would give the layer name the feature class name?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug? Suggest you contact esri support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, this does look like a bug -- this seems specific to using the **iterator**, with the **inline variable** and **running the model in edit mode**

You can get around this and achieve your result by:

- Adding **Collect Values** to your model. Wire up the output of Feature to Line to Collect Values.
- Make the Collect Values a **Model Parameter** (make sure the Feature to Line output is NOT a parameter)
- Run the model as a **tool**, not from the edit window.
- Everything gets added to the Table of Contents with the expected name.